# Variables won't update in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a problem in my vb.net code, I have a login form that is connected to a mysql database. It can already check if the user is in the database, now the next thing to do is to get the name, access level and userId from the database according to the logged in account, I have store it in a module that holds a global variable.

This is my code.

```
Module pubvars
    Public Gplev As String
    Public Gname As String
    Public GuserId As Integer
End Module
```

Then I will use this variables on other forms, in the first session of logging in the variables was read correctly,but when I logged out, then login with a new user account, the variable passed was not updated, which is supposedly changed as a new account was logged in.

Here is the code where I declare the variables.

```
Dim search1 As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE login.username = '" & TextBox1.Text & "' AND login.password = '" & TextBox2.Text & "'", con)
con.Open()
Dim dr As MySqlDataReader = search1.ExecuteReader
Dim userFound As Boolean = False

While dr.Read
    userFound = True
    pubvars.Gname = dr("name").ToString
    pubvars.Gplev = dr("permission_level").ToString
    pubvars.GuserId = dr("userId").ToString
End While

If userFound = True Then
    main_menu.Show()
    Me.Hide()
Else
    MsgBox("Sorry, username or password not found", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Invalid Login")
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
End If
```

And here is the code where I used the variables in the second form.

```
 Private Sub main_menu_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Label3.Text = pubvars.Gname
    If pubvars.Gplev = "2" Then
        Button8.Enabled = False
        Button8.Visible = False
    ElseIf pubvars.Gplev = "3" Then
        Button8.Enabled = False
        Button8.Visible = False
    ElseIf pubvars.Gplev = "4" Then
        Button8.Enabled = False
        Button8.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

For logout I have the following code.Is this right or it is not enough for logout?

```
 Private Sub Button7_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
   pubvars.Gname = ""
   pubvars.Gplev = "0"
   login.Show()
   Me.Hide()
 End Sub
```

Comment: Are you finding the user, getting to the 2nd form and then pubvars is no longer storing your values?

Comment: @Mort pubvars is no longer passing the value to the 2nd form after loggin on different account, or the label3, that supposedly showing the value inside the puvars is not displaying the value. something like that happened.

Comment: That looks like it should work.  Set a breakpoint and step thru to make sure that code runs for the new login

Comment: @Plutonix Yes actually it works for the first try or first login, the label3 shows the name of the user but when I logout and login again with a different account, the label3 does not display the name of the user of the second account. I have run a test if the name was pulled out correctly from the database and it is, but when i tested if it is shown in the 2nd form, it returns nothing, so its like nothing to show.

Comment: Form load runs once and only once. if you just hide the form to login again, none of the code to use those vars will run.  Create a public method like `NewLogIn()` and put the form load code there. *Breakpoints* will verify if this is the case

Comment: Move the login var assignment logic from Load event to Activated event

Comment: @George Thank you that did the trick!!!

Comment: Glad to help. I created an answer so you can accept it, if you don't mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the login var assignment logic from Load event to Activated event. The Load event gets executed only once, when you load a Form for the first time.

The Activated event happens every time you display the form `.Show()`. If you move the code from Load event to Activated, you should fix the issue.